# Авторизация/аутентификация в приложении c# с БД MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, авторизация

Как можно более удобно сделать процесс авторизации с труднейшим способом ее взлома. 
Если писать в коде - код легко доступен - взлом легкий.
Если писать в таблицу БД, то к данным БД мы будем иметь доступ раньше, чем нам это нужно будет.

Comment: Используйте шифрование ассиметричными ключами (как в SSL). MSSQL последних версий имеет встроеную поддержку асиметричных ключей.

Comment: В случае винформ - никак. У пользователя есть доступ ко всем тем данным,  к которым есть доступ у приложения. Совершенно бесполезно строить хитрую схему аутентификации в десктопе. Единственный надежный способ - убрать ее на сервер,  вне доступа пользователя